# How can i write JSGF grammar file with unknown in advance word?

Tags: java, voice-recognition, cmusphinx

How can i write JSGF grammar file with unknown in advance word?

For example i want match
"Give me the chair please",
"Give me the book please",
etc.

using similar construction

```
public <sent> = Give me <any_word> please;
```

How can i do this?

Comment: did you succeed to write JSGF grammar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create a grammar for any word.

You can list predefined list of words instead of `<any_word>` and this list could be large, say 100000 entries covering 99% of English language.

Comment: Bad news. I need do this for getting <any_word> after cathcing. I can't predefine all words(